# How do you add JOOQ's 3.17 snaphot build to maven?

Tags: jooq

Does JOOQ push the latest non-stable builds to maven central? Or is there some snapshot repo I need to add to pom.xml?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Does JOOQ push the latest non-stable builds to maven central?

Snapshot builds are offered only to paying customers, available from here: https://www.jooq.org/download/versions

> Or is there some snapshot repo I need to add to pom.xml?

The above website offers ZIP file downloads. The ZIP file contains two scripts:

- `maven-install.sh` and `maven-install.bat` to install the snapshot artifacts locally, to your local repository (e.g. `~/.m2`)
- `maven-deploy.sh` and `maven-deploy.bat` to deploy the snapshot artifacts to your artifact repository

There are other options, e.g. using the `maven-install-plugin` in your build, of course, or build and install the snapshots directly from source code

Comment: I guess it's time to send Lukas some money.  Thanks again.  Love your product!

Comment: @benstpierre. Excellent! :) Well you get more out of it, too: https://www.jooq.org/download/#feature-comparison